# Can a macro be used in inline asm?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86, kernel

code as following:

```
\#define CS 0x18

asm ("pushl CS"
    );
```

or something as an input argument:

```
asm("pushl %0 \n\t"

     :"m"(CS) \

    )
```

can the macro CS be used in the above inline asm code?

Comment: If you're talking abut the GNU toolchain then yes - what happened to make you think that you couldn't ?

Comment: Only the latter would work. Thats possibly not obvious to everyone

Comment: @PaulR:I am not familiar with asm, do you mean that the two forms above are both right?

Comment: You won't get macro substitution inside quoted strings, so as @drhirsch says, the first example won't work but the second one should

Comment: @PaulR:does asm("pushl "CS); work?

Comment: You would need to use the preprocessor stringify operator to make this work, e.g. `asm("pushl " #CS);`. Or you could define CS as a string, e.g. `#define CS "0x18"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CS can be used in the second example, not the first.

Macros are substituted before the compiler/assembler work, so they work regardless of C or assembly.
But macros are not expanded in strings, so the first example won't work.

If you want to make the first example work, use stringization:

```
#define STR1(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR1(x)
asm ("pushl " STR(CS));
```

This expands `STR(CS)` to `"0x18"` and concatenates it with `"pushl "`.

Answer (score -1):

or build one inside the x86 asm

```
call macro1 ;from anywhere in asm code


.macro1
do stuff
ret
```